# How to fix this error of Invalid Resx file? Invalid length of Base-64 array or string. When opening the solution, an error appears on main designer

Tags: c#, replace, windows-forms-designer

I've tried to change something in form with Ctrl+h shortcut, then realised, that I've switched "mA" with "A", but not in my designer. It happened for all the files I guess. I could undo the operation, but it seems to not working because of that replace try.
I see the error:

Invalid Resx file. Invalid length of Base-64 array or string. line 575, item 5.

It's actually row with "", you can see it below:
[image: Image when you can see the error that appears while debugging]

I've tried to restore git repository and even though I can't see any changes, the error is still there, while opening the solution:

[image: The error visible after opening the solution]

I've tried to restore git repository to get my solution without changes. It seemed to be a good idea, but it failed in fact... The problem is still there.

I've also tried to find any strings contained "mA", that could be replaced by "m". I've found it in several places in Test.resx file, but it was before I restored my repository. Now when I try to see the Test.resx file, I get:

[image: Error that I get while opening Test.resx file]

Which means that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"